# Combine two tables and create new columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (see also: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/573):

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id serial,
  time timestamp,
  temperature double precision,
  instrument text
);

INSERT INTO test1 (time, temperature, instrument) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:24:02', 25.2, 'sensor1');
INSERT INTO test1 (time, temperature, instrument) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:24:02', 26.2, 'sensor2');
INSERT INTO test1 (time, temperature, instrument) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:25:02', 25.3, 'sensor1');
INSERT INTO test1 (time, temperature, instrument) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:25:02', 26.3, 'sensor2');
INSERT INTO test1 (time, temperature, instrument) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:26:03', 25.3, 'sensor1');
INSERT INTO test1 (time, temperature, instrument) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:26:03', 26.3, 'sensor2');

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id serial,
  time timestamp,
  humidity double precision
);

INSERT INTO test2 (time, humidity) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:24:02', 85);
INSERT INTO test2 (time, humidity) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:25:02', 86);
INSERT INTO test2 (time, humidity) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:26:03', 87);
INSERT INTO test2 (time, humidity) VALUES ('2020-08-20 11:27:03', 88);
```

I would like to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM test1 JOIN test2 ON test1.time = test2.time
```

The result from this query is what I need:

```
| id  | time                     | temperature | instrument | id  | time                     | humidity |
| --- | ------------------------ | ----------- | ---------- | --- | ------------------------ | -------- |
| 1   | 2020-08-20T11:24:02.000Z | 25.2        | sensor1    | 1   | 2020-08-20T11:24:02.000Z | 85       |
| 2   | 2020-08-20T11:24:02.000Z | 26.2        | sensor2    | 1   | 2020-08-20T11:24:02.000Z | 85       |
| 3   | 2020-08-20T11:25:02.000Z | 25.3        | sensor1    | 2   | 2020-08-20T11:25:02.000Z | 86       |
| 4   | 2020-08-20T11:25:02.000Z | 26.3        | sensor2    | 2   | 2020-08-20T11:25:02.000Z | 86       |
| 5   | 2020-08-20T11:26:03.000Z | 25.3        | sensor1    | 3   | 2020-08-20T11:26:03.000Z | 87       |
| 6   | 2020-08-20T11:26:03.000Z | 26.3        | sensor2    | 3   | 2020-08-20T11:26:03.000Z | 87       |
```

However I would like to have the result formatted as follows:

```
time                     | humidity | sensor1 | sensor2 |
------------------------ | -------- | ------- | ------- |
2020-08-20T11:24:02.000Z | 85       | 25.2    | 26.2    |
2020-08-20T11:25:02.000Z | 86       | 25.3    | 26.3    |
2020-08-20T11:26:03.000Z | 87       | 25.3    | 26.3    |
```

I have no idea how to achieve this, I would like to have the column labels (sensor1, sensor2) to be taken from the data.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Ok, so how would I rewrite this select using a join?

Comment: Simply `FROM test1 JOIN test2 ON test1.time = test2.time`. Same result, but in a better way.

Comment: Ah, too simple.....thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any constraint, so I would try like this:

```
select test1.time,
       max(test2.humidity) as humidity,
       max(case when test1.instrument = 'sensor1' then temperature end) as sensor1,
       max(case when test1.instrument = 'sensor2' then temperature end) as sensor2       
  from test1
  join test2 on test1.time = test2.time
 group by test1.time
 order by test1.time
```

Comment: thanks (same comment as above) this works well, but I have to specify the name of the columns (sensor1, sensor2) in the query. Can this somehow be done automatic? I will update the question, as that was actually my main problem.

Comment: No you cannot get data values as column names. The column names comes from the name of the column selected or an alias to a selected column, a calculation, or static value in select list.

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, you should do this using `filter`:

```
SELECT t2.time, t2.humidity,
       MAX(t1.temperature) FILTER (WHERE t1.instrument = 'sensor1') as sensor1,
       MAX(t1.temperature) FILTER (WHERE t1.instrument = 'sensor2') as sensor2
FROM test1 t1 JOIN
     test2 
     ON t1.time = t2.time
GROUP BY t2.time, t2.humidity
```

Comment: thanks, this works well, but I have to specify the name of the columns (sensor1, sensor2) in the query. Can this somehow be done automatic? I will update the question, as that was actually my main problem.